# Powershell Pipe and Foreach-Object in c#

Tags: c#, powershell, foreach, office365, powershell-remoting

I am invoking a get-msoluser cmdlet of office365 and i use the following cmdlet in powershell

```
 Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@organization.onmicrosoft.com | ForEach-Object{ $_.licenses}
```

The output is a collection of licenses and i wanted the same script to be run in c#. so i have written the code as follows

```
private void displayLicenses(){
     Command cmd = new Command("Get-MsolUser");
     cmd.Parameters.Add("UserPrincipalName","user@organization.onmicrosoft.com");
     Command cmd2 = new Command("ForEach-Object");
     cmd2.Parameters.Add("$_.licenses.AccountSku");
     Pipeline pipe = Office365Runspace.CreatePipeline();
     pipe.Commands.Add(cmd);
     pipe.Commands.Add(cmd2);
     Console.WriteLine("Before invoking the pipe");
     ICollection<PSObject> result = pipe.Invoke();
     CheckForErrors(pipe);
     Console.WriteLine("Executed command {0} + {1} with no error", cmd.CommandText, cmd2.CommandText);
      foreach(PSObject obj in result){
            foreach(PSPropertyInfo propInfo in obj.Properties){
                Console.WriteLine(propInfo.Name+": "+propInfo.Value+" "+propInfo.MemberType);
          }
     }
}
```

But i still get an error on executing this function saying

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term
>   'ForEach-Object' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   scrip t file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
>   if a path was in cluded, verify that the path is correct and try
>   again.

I checked that my project has a reference to System.management.Automation.dll file that contains the ForEach-Object cmdlet.

I found the dll using this cmd in powershell

```
(Get-Command ForEach-Object).dll
```

Thanks,
Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem causing for the issue. It is due to the misconfigured runspace i created.

```
    InitialSessionState initalState = InitialSessionState.Create();
    initalState.ImportPSModule(new String[] { "msonline" });
    //initalState.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;

    Office365Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initalState);
    Office365Runspace.Open();
```

i was creating the initalstate with empty one,When i changed it to default one it worked fine.On creating the default one it includes all the modules that were obtained by default.

```
  InitialSessionState initalState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
```

it worked fine.

Thanks,
Satya

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your're trying to run that in the remote session at the Exchange server.  Those are NoLanguage constrained sessions, meaning that you can only run the Exchange cmdlets in those sessions.  If you want to use PowerShell core language cmdlets (like foreach-object), you have to do that in a local session and either use Import-PSSession to import the Exchange functions into your local session (implicit remoting) , or use Invoke-Command and point it at the remote session on the Exchange server.

Comment: i am doing the office365 cmdlet and i imported the msonline functions to my office365 runspace.